# How can I concatenate two byte* (secblock) with operator 'secblock<T, A>::operator+='

Tags: c++, crypto++, allocator

Please little example. I tried use this as in documentation, but I can not understand how to.

Messages:

```
main.cpp|97|error: no matching function for call to 
   'CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char>::operator+=(CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char>*)'
   secblock.h|568|note: candidate: 
   CryptoPP::SecBlock<T, A>& CryptoPP::SecBlock<T, A>::operator+=(const CryptoPP::SecBlock<T, A>&)
   [with T = unsigned char; A = CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char>]
   secblock.h|568|note:   
   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char>*' 
   to 'const CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char>&'
```

My code:

```
SecBlock<byte, AllocatorWithCleanup<byte> > hash_ripemd160_temp;
  RIPEMD160().CalculateDigest(hash_ripemd160_temp, hash_sha256, 32);

  SecBlock<byte, AllocatorWithCleanup<byte> > hash_ripemd160 = L0_byte;

   hash_ripemd160 = SecBlock< byte , AllocatorWithCleanup<byte > >::operator+= (&hash_ripemd160_temp);
```

In Docs is as:

```
SecBlock<byte , AllocatorWithCleanup<byte > >& SecBlock< byte , AllocatorWithCleanup<byte > >::operator+= (const SecBlock< byte , AllocatorWithCleanup<byte > > &t)     
Append contents from another SecBlock.

Parameters

t   the other SecBlock

Internally, this SecBlock calls Grow and then copies the new content.

If the memory block is reduced in size, then the unused area is set to 0.
```

Definition at line 568 of file secblock.h.

Comment: Вадим and Alan... Thanks again for your help with the issue. It really annoys me we did not catch it sooner. I'll be re-evaluating our engineering process looking for the gaps during the postmortem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to call an operator function is to just use the operator:

```
  hash_ripemd160 += hash_ripemd160_temp;
```

If you want to call it directly (which I would not recommend) you have to call it like this, since it is a member function:

```
hash_ripemd160.operator += (hash_ripemd160_temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I concatenate two byte* (secblock) with `operator 'secblock<T, A>::operator+='`

Try the following *after* you pull [commit 605744d8260c6ada](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/605744d8260c6ada033805c13ae0b2646acf18d6). (Or perform a fresh checkout with `git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git`).

```
$ cat test.cxx 
#include "ripemd.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "hex.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SecByteBlock digest(RIPEMD160::DIGESTSIZE);
  RIPEMD160 hash;

  std::string message("now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country");
  HexEncoder hexer(new FileSink(cout));

  // RIPEMD-160
  hash.Update((const byte*)message.data(), message.size());
  hash.TruncatedFinal(digest, digest.size());

  cout << "RIPEMD-160: ";
  hexer.Put(digest, digest.size());
  cout << endl;

  // Double it
  digest += digest;

  cout << "RIPEMD-160 (x2): ";
  hexer.Put(digest, digest.size());
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

You and Alan uncovered the the typos in the `assert`. I was not aware the self tests did not exercise the code paths. That's now been fixed, and we opened another issue to address the defect in the engineering process: [Need a Code Coverage tool added to the Release Process](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/93).

---

You also uncovered a nasty little bug in self-concatenation (i.e., `digest += digest`). It has been been changed to the following to detect it:

```
SecBlock<T, A>& operator+=(const SecBlock<T, A> &t)
{
    assert((!t.m_ptr && !t.m_size) || (t.m_ptr && t.m_size));

    if(t.m_size)
    {
        if(this != &t)  // s += t
        {
            const size_type oldSize = m_size;
            Grow(m_size+t.m_size);
            memcpy_s(m_ptr+oldSize, (m_size-oldSize)*sizeof(T), t.m_ptr, t.m_size*sizeof(T));
        }
        else            // t += t
        {
            SecBlock result(m_size+t.m_size);
            if(m_size) {memcpy_s(result.m_ptr, result.m_size*sizeof(T), m_ptr, m_size*sizeof(T));}
            memcpy_s(result.m_ptr+m_size, (result.m_size-m_size)*sizeof(T), t.m_ptr, t.m_size*sizeof(T));
            swap(result);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Prior to the fix/commit, it looks like it should trigger an `InvalidArgument` exception under most conditions. However, there are some corner cases on Windows that we are not so sure about which could lead to a silent truncation.

The silent truncation is concerning, and we are debating a Crypto++ 5.6.4 release.

Comment: Result: EEE46B312007181E9B2E48C9361A58CC26EF1EBD and EEE46B312007181E9B2E48C9361A58CC26EF1EBDEEE46B312007181E9B2E48C9361A58CC26EF1EBD respectively. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` before `hash_ripemd160_temp`

```
hash_ripemd160 = SecBlock< byte , AllocatorWithCleanup<byte > >::operator+= (hash_ripemd160_temp);
```

The operator accepts the object, not the pointer.